# hostname -f says "hostname: the specified hostname is invalid". Guess why?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, hostname, hosts

hostname -f says "hostname: the specified hostname is invalid". The hostname (FQDN) specified in /etc/hostname is also listed in /etc/hosts and is pingable. No actual DNS server yet of the host knows. Is this a reason of the error reported or something else? (the OS is Ubuntu 10.04 Server).

Update: registering the host at a DNS server (so that the name can be successfully resolved via Internet) did not help.

Comment: Well... what's the contents of /etc/hostname or do we need to guess that too?

Comment: Please share the contents of your /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts. Maybe the hostname is in fact invalid.

Answer (score 14):

From [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1640679).

Apparently the underscore is an illegal character for hostnames.  I had one in my hostname, and it gave me your failure message.  Maybe you're getting something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Check the configuration of:

```
/etc/host.conf
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

host.conf should have "order hosts, bind" and nsswitch.conf should have "hosts: files dns" at a minimum. Possibly you've got something out of whack that's searching only DNS and not your local files?

Comment: clearly not the problem.

Comment: Al that's there.

Comment: solved the problem for me, Host \209\149something.sld.tld returned servfail - it looked ok though, osx terminal injecting funny things again ;)

Answer (score 1):

/etc/hostname should only contain the hostname and not a full FQDN.

Comment: Tried this. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

`hostname -f` relies on DNS working.

What does:

```
host `cat /etc/hostname`
```

print?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your hostname at `/etc/hostname` or directly from the CLI [like this](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/3151/etchosts):

```
echo "<desired_hostname>" > /etc/hostname hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

For systems that support it (such as Ubuntu 18.04+), you can also use [`hostnamectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html) like this:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname <desired_hostname>
```

Then reboot or login/logout and you should see the latest hostname, regardless of illegal characters like underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, underscores are not allowed - and hyphens and numbers have limited places allowed within the domain name.
Just for reference, the allowed characters to be used in DNS FQDNs (hostnames) are defined in RFC 1034 - they were already using similar conventions but this is the basis for DNS standards (also RFC 1035 but 1034 deals specifically with allowed format and characters.
From the RFC:

> Note that while upper and lower case letters are allowed in domain
> names, no significance is attached to the case.  That is, two names
> with the same spelling but different case are to be treated as if
> identical.
>
> The labels must follow the rules for ARPANET host names.  They must
> start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior
> characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also some
> restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or less.
>
> For example, the following strings identify hosts in the Internet:
>
> A.ISI.EDU  XX.LCS.MIT.EDU  SRI-NIC.ARPA